# Is it possible to implement dynamic webpage using RAW API of LwIP (Light weight IP).?

Tags: webserver, microchip, lwip, mcu

I would like to know if we can implement dynamic webpage using RAW API of LWIP.? (without using threads and OS)

Any resources where I could refer for more details.?

I'm using SAM V71 MCU where I have flashed code and able to get static web page upon entering IP Address.

Board is SAM V71 Xplained Ultra

Right now I implemented webpage containing button , upon clicking on button, GET Request will be transmitted to MCU and MCU able to read request and not sending back response.